# .local domain resolving problem in 20.04

Tags: 22.04, dns, systemd-resolved

I have DNS server with domains in .local zone. After changing priorities in /etc/nsswitch.conf and adding subconfig with my domains to /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/ i have servfail error (local cache server can't find my domain) when trying to resolve this domain name. In resolvectl output my domain available in Global section, but don't apply to interfaces. In other systems (18.04 and 20.04) all working good.
Suspect it has to do with systemd changes but can't figure out how to fix it. Replacing the /etc/resolv.conf link with /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf doesn't suit me.
Parts of my configs:
**/etc/systemd/resolved.conf**

```
[Resolve]
Domains=mydomain.com ~local ~mydomain.local ~myseconddomain.local
```

**/etc/nsswitch.conf**

```
hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal
```

Part of **resolvectl** output

```
   Global
          Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   resolv.conf mode: stub
         DNS Domain: mydomain.com
                     ~local ~mydomain.local ~myseconddomain.local
   
   Link 2 (enp0s3)
       Current Scopes: DNS
            Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   Current DNS Server: 10.0.2.3
          DNS Servers: 10.0.2.3
           DNS Domain: mydomain.com
```

Comment: If you are going to continue to use `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` as your resolver, you can specify what DNS servers and search Domain you want in the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file.  It can give you more control over your settings.  Once you make any changes to that file you should restart the `resolved` service.  `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`

Comment: So, my domains specisied in **/etc/systemd/resolved.conf** and are shown in resolvectl output, but only in **Global** section. Resolving of .local domain don't working

Comment: "/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf doesn't suit me" what does that mean?  If you change to that file then you will see whatever your DHCP is handing down like your domain name.  If you stick with the `stub-resolv.conf` then it does its own thing.

Comment: I meant that changing the link, as is often advised, does not work for me.

Comment: You only have to change it once unless you reinstall.  How often is someone advising it?

Comment: For some reason, this is often recommended for a case like mine

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found it easier to use `avahi` rather than `systemd-resolved`. All it took to solve get mDNS up and running on Ubuntu was

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
```

That's it.

Disclaimer: I don't know what the downsides of this solution may be, so please do leave a comment if I missed something.

Comment: perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly the same issue on Linux Mint 21 while trying to set up my network printer. After a few hours of searching, I came across [this blog post](https://wlog.viltstigen.se/articles/2021/05/02/mdns-for-linux/) which confirmed what the manpages hinted at.

Essentially, you have to enable `MulticastDNS` (a.k.a. `mDNS`) for the interface that connects to your router, which is usually your wlan.

So first modify `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
[Resolve]
# Uncomment and set these values
DNS=192.168.1.1
Domains=local
MulticastDNS=yes
LLMNR=no
```

You have correctly identified that modifying this file only affects the `Global` section of the `resolvectl status` output. In order to change the configuration of the other *links* you have to create a separate `.network` entry for every *link* (in my case, the wlan link had the name `wlp2s0`; use your own name in the steps below).

Now create a new file

```bash
sudo touch /etc/systemd/network/wlp2s0.network
```

In that file, specify the configuration for the `wlp2s0` *link*

```
[Match]
Name=wlp2s0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
MulticastDNS=yes
LLMNR=no
```

After that, enable and start `systemd-networkd` if it isn't enabled by default

```bash
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
```

Then check if the `wlp2s0.network` configuration got loaded

```bash
networkctl list
```

Which should print

```
IDX LINK      TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo        loopback carrier     unmanaged 
  2 enp1s0    ether    no-carrier  unmanaged 
  3 wlp2s0    wlan     routable    configured
```

Lastly restart `sytstemd-resolved`

```bash
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

and check the status

```bash
systemctl status
```

It should say

```
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
        DNS Domain: local

Link 2 (enp1s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp2s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS mDNS/IPv4 mDNS/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1 xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx::x
        DNS Domain: Home
```

Now you can try and ping your `.local` domain

```bash
ping myprinter.local
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 22.04 and Linux Mint 21.2. The problem is that the domain is added in the DNS-request.

E.g. you're using `mydomain.com` and internal you also want to use `mytest.local`.
`host.mytest.local` normally is a FQDN, but Mint and Ubuntu are adding the domain to the DNS-request, so it looks like this:

```
**host.mytest.local.mydomain.com**
```

I've added both domains to the domain search list in my DHCP-server.
Now it works.